# Generador aleatorio y bucle infinito semi-controlado

Tags: javascript

### EDIT 2

```js
var i  = prompt('Ńumero de veces iterado:');
while(!i || isNaN(i)){
  var i = prompt('Número de veces iterado:')
}
var n = 0;

const getInput = () => {
  const isOk = input => !!input && !isNaN(+input);
  
    const input = prompt('Enter an initial value');
  return isOk(input)
    ? +input 
    : getInput();
}

const getIterationFn = initial => {
    let value = initial;
    return () => {
    // Hace el cálculo de decremento
    const decrement = () => {
      const y = value * r;
      const res = value - y;
      const sum = value - res;
      //console.log(`You lose ${sum.toFixed(2)}€`);      

      // Actualiza el valor
      value -= sum;
      console.log(`Total: ${value.toFixed(2)}`);
    }

    // Hace el cálculo ed incremento
    const increment = () => {
      const y = value / r;
      const sum = y - value;
      //console.log(`You earned ${sum.toFixed(2)}€`);

      // Actualiza el valor
      value += sum;
      console.log(`Total: ${value.toFixed(2)}`);
    }

    const r = Math.random();
    // Selecciona qué acción va a hacer
    // en función del valor de r.
    const action = r < 0.5 
      ? decrement
      : increment;
    while(n<=i){
      action();
      n++;
    }
  }
}

const interval = 1000;
const input = getInput();

  setInterval(
  getIterationFn(input),  // Acción a ejecutar
  interval              // Tiempo entre ejecución y ejecución
  );
```

Conseguí ejecutar la acción el número determinado de veces por prompt. PERO, no conseguí hacer la acción por cada intervalo, osea, cada segundo que me saque un valor.

¿Cómo podría corregir esto?

Comment: Básicamente quieres que se ejecute la función `sumSum` cada cinco segundos, ¿es eso?

Comment: Eso es, pedir una sola vez por el prompt la el valor, y a raiz de ello, ir operando hacia arriba o hacia abajo, siempre cambiando el valor X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ejecutar una acción repetidamente cada cierto tiempo, puedes usar [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Como primer argumento pasamos la función a ejecutarse y como segundo parámetro el intervalo entre ejecuciones.

El siguiente *script* ejecutará la función `action` cada 5 segundos.

```
const interval = 5000; // 5s
const action = () => {
    console.log(`Executing stuff`);
}

setInterval(action, interval);
```

---

En tu caso, definimos el *input* del usuario.

```
const getInput = () => {
  const isOk = input => !!input && !isNaN(+input);
  
  const input = prompt('Enter an initial value');
  return isOk(input)
    ? +input 
    : getInput();
}
```

Después, la función que será ejecutada cada 5 segundos. Hará el cálculo y actualizará la variable con el valor calculado (he renombrado `x` por `value`).

```
const iteration = () => {
  // Hace el cálculo de decremento
  const decrement = () => {
    const y = value * r;
    const res = value - y;
    const sum = value - res;
    console.log(`You lose ${sum.toFixed(2)}€`);      

    // Actualiza el valor 
    value -= sum;
    console.log(`Total: ${value}`);
  }

  // Hace el cálculo ed incremento
  const increment = () => {
    const y = value / r;
    const sum = y - value;
    console.log(`You earned ${sum.toFixed(2)}€`);

    // Actualiza el valor
    value += sum;
    console.log(`Total: ${value.toFixed(2)}`);
  }

  const r = Math.random();
  // Selecciona qué acción va a hacer
  // en función del valor de r.
  const action = r < 0.5 
  ? decrement
  : increment;

  action();    
}
```

Ahora, necesitamos preservar el valor actual en todo momento. Por eso definimos una función que recibirá por parámetro el valor inicial (el que el usuario ha introducido) y devolverá la función `iteration`.
Como `iteration` estará en el *scope* de su función padre, tendrá acceso a la variable `value`.

```
const getIterationFn = initial => {
  let value = initial;
  return () => {
    // Código de la función iteration ...
  }
}
```

> Hay muchas formas de hacer esto. Puedes encontrar la que más te convenga.
> Lo importante es que veas que en tu código hay una clara ambigüedad entre la `x` (el valor introducido por el usuario) y la `x` (el parámetro de la función `sumSum`).
> Dentro de la función `sumSum`, `x` hace referencia al parámetro.
> La primera vez que `sumSum` es invocada (la invoca la función `setTimeout`) no le pasa ningún parámetro (por defecto), por lo que `x` es `undefined`.

Finalmente, invocamos `setInterval` con el resultado de `getIterationFn`.

```
const interval = 5000; // 5s
const input = getInput();
setInterval(
  getIterationFn(input),  // Acción a ejecutar
  interval                // Tiempo entre ejecución y ejecución
);
```

Dejo [un *fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/VRoxa/omwv1set/30/) con todo el código.

---

**Edit 1**
La función `setInterval` devuelve la instancia de ese intervalo. Con esa referencia, podemos cancelarlo con la función `clearInterval`.

```
// ...
const runningInterval = setInterval(
  getIterationFn(input),
  interval
);

// En el momento que quieras pararlo
clearInterval(runningInterval);
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Todo perfecto, pero te voy a hacer una pregunta teórica. En las líneas 40 y 41 usas `?` y `:` para hacer una función u otra dependiendo del resultado. ¿Cómo funciona esa selección? Y ¿por qué funciona con r < 0.5?

Comment: Hago también una edición al código que pasaste, para ver cómo poder darle una vuelta de hoja y programar un fin del bucle.

Comment: Hola, @AQMR. En primer lugar, no es más que una [operación ternaria](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Con la condición `r < 0.5` devuelvo una función y otra y la guardo en la constante `action`. Después, invocaré `action` que será `increment` o bien `decrement`.

Comment: Para cancelarlo, debes guardar el intervalo en una constante y cuando quieras pararlo, llamar a `clearInterval`. Mejor añado una pequeña explicación en la respuesta.

Comment: Pero haciendo a setInterval una constante, no se ejecuta el bucle, necesitaría llamar a runningInterval todo el rato, no?

Comment: No, `setInterval` "inicializa" el *interval*. Éste empezará a correr y llamará a tu función cada X tiempo.

Comment: Nada, estoy intentando implementarlo desde que me lo dijiste y 0 resultados, o consigo que se haga infinito y se ejecute `n` numero de veces por invervalo, o no consigo nada. Ten en cuenta que soy newbie.

Comment: Te he actualizado el [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VRoxa/omwv1set/35/) con ese cambio, @AQMR. Échale un vistazo

Comment: También me vale con el botón, muy bueno, ya lo había pensado, pero quise programar yo mismo el número de iteraciones. Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

En vez de usar un `setTimeout`, debería usar un `setInterval`... y como quieres que se ejecute cada 5 segundos, no debes llamar a `sumSum` dentro de si misma... es decir... así:

```js
function randomRNG(){

    var x = prompt('inserta un valor');
    while(!x || isNaN(x)){
        x = prompt('inserta un valor');
    }

    function sumSum(x){
        var rnd = Math.random();

        if(rnd<=0.5){
            var y = x*rnd;
            var res = x-y;
            var sum = x-res;
            console.log('has perdido '+sum.toFixed(2)+'€');
            var x = res.toFixed(2);
            console.log('TOTAL :'+x+'€');
            //sumSum(x);
        }
        if(rnd>0.5){
            var y = x/rnd;
            var sum = y-x;
            console.log('has ganado '+sum.toFixed(2)+'€');
            var x = y.toFixed(2);
            console.log('TOTAL: '+x+'€');
            //sumSum(x);
        }
    }
    
    setInterval(function(){ sumSum(x); }, 5000);
}

randomRNG()
```

Answer (score 0):

Vale, para controlar que se haga cada segundo la iteración, y cerrar el bucle, hay que añadir un while debajo del action() y un n++ fuera del while:

```js
//Damos el numero de iteraciones que quiere ejecutarse
var i  = prompt('Ńumero de veces iterado:');
while(!i || isNaN(i)){
  var i = prompt('Número de veces iterado:')
}
//Definimos como 1 el valor total de n. No puede variar.
var n = 1;


//Hacemos a getInput una variable
const getInput = () => {
  const isOk = input => !!input && !isNaN(+input);  //Analiza si es un valor numerico
  
    const input = prompt('Elige un valor inicial');  //Metemos el valor en la constante input
  return isOk(input)  //retorna la constante isOk con parametro input
    ? +input //Operacion ternaria, si es TRUE, hace +input
    : getInput(); //Operacion ternaria, si es FALSE, hace getInput()
}

const getIterationFn = initial => {
    let value = initial;
    return () => {
    // Hace el calculo de decremento
    const decrement = () => {
      const y = value * r;
      const res = value - y;
      const sum = value - res;     
      // Actualiza el valor
      value -= sum;
      console.log(`Total: ${value.toFixed(2)}`);
    }

    // Hace el cálculo de incremento
    const increment = () => {
      const y = value / r;
      const sum = y - value;
      // Actualiza el valor
      value += sum;
      console.log(`Total: ${value.toFixed(2)}`);
    }

    const r = Math.random();
    // Selecciona qué acción va a hacer
    // en función del valor de r.
    const action = r < 0.5 
      ? decrement
      : increment;
    
    action();
    console.log(n);
    n++;
    if(n==i){
      clearInterval(runningInterval);
      console.log('Fin del bucle');
    }
  }
}

const interval = 1000;
const input = getInput();

const runningInterval = setInterval(
  getIterationFn(input),  // Acción a ejecutar
  interval              // Tiempo entre ejecución y ejecución
  );
```